# In using Firebase Authentication, are the passwords already encrypted?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In using Firebase Authentication for let's say a website where you can register/login, are the passwords already encrypted? The account of the user will be saved in the Firestore but it will only show the name and email of the user, the passwords are not shown in the firestore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firebase Authentication** uses an internally modified version of **scrypt** to hash account passwords. Even when an account is uploaded with a password using a different algorithm, Firebase Auth will rehash the password the first time that the account successfully logs in.

- Accounts downloaded from Firebase Authentication will only ever
  contain a password hash if one for this version of scrypt is
  available, or contain an empty password hash otherwise.

Here is the [Scrypt](https://github.com/SmartMoveSystems/firebase-scrypt-java) uses by firebase to hash password

Answer (score 2):

Yes the passwords are encripted by Firebase and you can't view them.

Comment: Firebase uses [Scrypt](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/hash/Scrypt) for encryption